# load file path in java failed in executable jar file

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am writing a program in java with netbeans IDE that recieves a jasper report file and displays it to the user.
so I wrote the following code:

```
String reportSource = null;
try {
    URL url = getClass().getResource("/mypkg/resources/jreports/report.jrxml");
    reportSource = url.getPath();
    reportSource = reportSource.replaceFirst("/", "");
    System.out.println(reportSource);
} catch (Exception ex) {}

try{
    JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(reportSource);
    JasperReport jasperReport = 
            JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = 
            JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, getConnection());
    JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, false);
}catch(Exception ex){}
```

my problem is that when i run my program from within the IDE it runs fine, but when I try to run the jar file from the dist folder it gave me the following exception

**java.io.FileNotFoundException**

what is the problem?

Comment: You sure you packing the file inside the jar?

Comment: And `URL` and a `File` not necessarily the same thing, a embedded resource can't be treated as a `File`

Comment: yes I put it in /mypkg/resources/jreports/report.jrxml

Comment: so what is the solution?

Comment: `JRXmlLoader.load(String)` is looking for a "file", instead, you probably need to use `JRXmlLoader.load(InputStream)`, using `Class#getResourceAsStream` instead